# How to convert number in start except last 4 digits in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

In below response I am getting "43445567665" this value when I am mapping biomatricData.ninId:

```
biomatricData.ninId = 43445567665
```

Now I have to display only last 4 digit and rest should come like `*`

I have to change `43445567665` in below format

Like - `*******7665`

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 10 }}>
  <RegularText text={'Nin Number :  '} textColor='grey' style={{ marginBottom: 5 }} />
  <Text>{biomatricData.ninId}</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that `biomatricData.ninId` in variable then complete action given below and just use that variable for show.

use following regex.

```js
var str = "43445567665";
var replaced = str.replace(/.(?=.{4,}$)/g, '*');
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829030/10182897) as example

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var numToBeConverted = 327364829364;
String(numToBeConverted).split("").reverse().map((e, i) => i >= 4 ? "*" : e).reverse().join("");
```

You can make it a function if you want

```
function convertToBiometric(num) {
     return String(num).split("").reverse().map((e, i) => i >= 4 ? "*" : e).reverse().join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using `Array` methods like this.

```
let numToBeConverted = '43445567665';

function covert(num){
  let arr = Object.values(num);
  return  arr.splice(0, arr.length-4).fill('*').join('')
  + arr.splice(-4).join('');
}

console.log(covert(numToBeConverted));
//output - "*******7665"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use String padding to add the * sign in our string values to convert our string in sensitive data

checkout the doc to apply string padding

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart