# Replace strings to tag in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to replace :: and ;; to

`const text = 'Welcome :: my ;;'.replace('::', <Strong>to</Strong>).replace(';;', <Strong>world</Strong>);`

I am getting this
`Welcome [object Object] my [object Object].`

Expected response `Welcome **to** my **world**.`

Can anyone please help me on that.

---

**Updated question**

There will be random text like this:

1. `Welcome :: my ;;`
2. `Welcome ;; my ::`
3. `Hello ::`

And replace `::` with dynamic value suppose `to` only and `;;` with dynamic value `world` only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace part of string with tag in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474506/replace-part-of-string-with-tag-in-jsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX elements are syntax sugar for React DOM elements, which are objects. A string on it's own won't carry information about things such as font size or weight, so it may be best to represent the whole thing by JSX. I think something along these lines would do it:

```js
const text = 'Welcome :: my ;;';
const myWorld = (
  <span>
    {text.split(' ').map((word, index) => {
      const space = index == 0 ? '' : ' ';
      if (word == '::') {
        return (<strong key={index}>{space + "to"}</strong>);
      } else if (word == ';;') {
        return (<strong key={index}>{space + "world"}</strong>);
      }

      return (<span key={index}>{space + word}</span>);
    }}
  </span>
);
```

---

If you need the replacements to be dynamic, you can create a function for this:

```js
// Example `replacements` object:
// { 
//   '::': 'to',
//   ';;': 'world',
// }

function replaceWithEmphasis(text, replacements) {
  const words = text.split(' ');
  
  return (
    <span> 
      {
        words.map((word, index) => {
          const replaced = replacements[word];

          // Preserve spaces between words
          const space = index == 0 ? '' : ' ';

          if (replaced != null) {
            return <strong key={index}>{space + replaced}</strong>;
          } else {
            return <span key={index}>{space + word}</span>;
          }
        })
      }
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Horn
Do you have any idea that if we need to replace dynamic value like instead of `to` or `world` to dynamic value will be replaced and its order is not fixed some time first `word` will come sometime first `to` and also number of pattern also not fixed like currently there are two patterns but sometime one pattern (`::`,  `;;`) ?

Comment: I have already updated answer please check once.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I edited my answer - Hope that answers your question! Also the previous answer didn't preserve spacing between words, so I've added that as well.

Comment: last question suppose if I want to pass className then it would work ? 
For example: 
replaceWithEmphasis(text, replacement, props)
and while return if I use <strong {...props}> </strong>then should css and other props will work ?

Comment: Sure - You can just pass a className argument to the function, and then use it in the case where you return the `strong` element: `<strong className={className} key={index}>{replaced}</strong>;` - Or something along those lines, depending on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Ok Thank you Michael Horn

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
const text = 'Welcome :: my ;;'.replace('::', '<strong>to</strong>').replace(';;', '<strong>world</strong>')
```

and then display it using dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
render() {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text  }} />
    );
  }
```