# ReactJS Automaticly Add Tooltips

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, tooltip

Say I have a `JS` file that contains a dictionary (an Object full of `key: value` pairs) and is exported to a `JSX` file.

How can I create a function that gets a string and returns a span with every word that exists both in the dictionary's `keys` and the string converted into a tooltip with the matching `value` as its content embedded with the rest of the non-tooltipped text (like Wikipedia, for reference)?

I've found [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/) tooltip library from `react-mui`, so creating the tooltip itself is not the problem, but only creating the function to convert all the occurrences automatically.

Below is the function that gets the `key` (name) and `value` (explanation) and converts them to a Tooltip:

```
function defToToolTip(name, explanation) {
  return <DictionaryTooltip title={explanation}>{name}</DictionaryTooltip>;
}
```

I've tried to create a function that gets a string and embeds tooltips wherever a word from the dictionary appears but got stuck very early.
I need help thinking about how to make sure all the words in the string that are also in the dictionary are converted using the function above.

Comment: Please add any relevant code (input, attempt at writing the code, expected output) to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: @Andy Added some code and explainings, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace part of string with tag in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474506/replace-part-of-string-with-tag-in-jsx)

Comment: @adsy if I had one value in my dictionary it could, but the newer solutions aren't working or can't be used with multiple values to replace.